# forcing and set theory

Tags: set-theory

Let  $\kappa , \lambda , \theta$ be infinte  cardinals de $M$ represents a c.t.m, and $P=Fn( \kappa\ \times \omega,2)$. Show that $(\lambda^{\theta})^{M[G]}\leq((max( \kappa, \lambda)^{\theta})^{M}$. as building function names of $\theta$ in $\lambda$

Comment: It might help to check out the FAQ and spend a little more time writing your question. Explain why you're interested, what's the motivation? Describe previous work on the topic, etc.

Comment: Is this homework? If not, what is the motivation?

Comment: Questions tend to end with question marks.

Answer (score 1):

Any function $f:\theta\to\lambda$ in the extension can be completely described by giving, in the ground model, for each $i\in\theta$, a "nice name" for $f(i)$.  A nice name amounts to a maximal antichain of conditions that decide particular values (in $\lambda$) for $f(i)$. So what you need to do is count (1) maximal antichains in your forcing (remember that it has the countable antichain condition), (2) count how many ways there are to label a maximal antichain with members of $\lambda$, and (3) count how many ways there are to assign such a labeled antichain (= nice name) to each element of $\theta$.